# In Swift 5, how do I efficiently extract and use elements in multidimensional arrays?

Tags: arrays, swift, multidimensional-array, time

New to programming this is my 5th day using swift/xcode, please be kind.

I have created an array of the format  - [[A], [B], [C], [D], [E], [F]], ... to serve as a look-up table. The requirement is to get the **A** - AM/PM, and **B, C - Start Time** and check if current time (hours, minutes) are within bounds of **D, E - End Time**, if so print the **message F** on a UILabel.

so for example if its 3.04 AM now my programme will use the table below to print "go to sleep, I'll let you know when its 4"

```
// [[A], [B], [C], [D], [E], [F]], ...


let messageArray : Array = [
                [["AM"], [00], [00], [00], [01], ["it's \nmidnight"]],
                [["AM"], [00], [02], [02], [59], ["it's very late (or early), \nto be up"]],
                [["AM"], [03], [00], [03], [01], ["are you ready \nfor the 03 am call?"]],
                [["AM"], [03], [02], [03], [59], ["go to sleep \ni'll let you know when it's \n4"]],...
```

I know how to get hour and minutes from current time.

```
let date = Date()
var calendar = Calendar.current

let hour = calendar.component(.hour, from: date)
let minute = calendar.component(.minute, from: date)
```

and that I need a outer and inner loop to traverse each x, y of the matrix. For each cell I need to extract the array and take the first 4 elements - AM/PM, startHour, startMinute, endHour, endMinute to check if current hour, minute are inside these bounds; but am not sure I understand multi-D array parsing. I have tried various things and tried looking up online but am struggling.

Should I even be using Arrays for this, is there some other more efficient data structure?

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: A Dictionary may be more appropriate for a lookup table.

Comment: Why do you need the innermost arrays or even better why not create a struct instead to hold the values of each row.

Comment: @koen Dictionaries can't match on intervals like that.

Comment: I never understood why `Date` models a Date+Time (I would expect it to be called `DateTime`, or `Instant`), and why there's no dedicate date-only or time-only datatype in Foundation.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica I agree. I use; `func fullDate() -> Array<Any> {
    let dateText = DateFormatter.localizedString(from: Date(), dateStyle: .full, timeStyle: .none)
    let dateArray = dateText.components(separatedBy: ", ")
    return(dateArray)
}

func fullTime() -> Array<Any> {
    let timeText = DateFormatter.localizedString(from: Date(), dateStyle: .none, timeStyle: .full)
    let timeArray = timeText.components(separatedBy: " ")
    return(timeArray)
}`

Comment: @Harvey Return isn't a function, don't add needles parentheses to it. `Array<Any>` is always suspect though. Better make a `Time` struct, like Jonathan did below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own struct, something like this:

```
enum AmPm {
    case am, pm
}
struct TimeMessage {
    var ampm: AmPm
    var hourStart: Int
    var minuteStart: Int
    var hourEnd: Int
    var minuteEnd: Int
    var message: String
}
```

With some convenience methods and properties:

```
extension TimeMessage {
    init(_ ampm: AmPm, _ hourStart: Int, _ minuteStart: Int, _ hourEnd: Int, _  minuteEnd: Int, _ message: String) {
        self.ampm = ampm
        self.hourStart = hourStart
        self.minuteStart = minuteStart
        self.hourEnd = hourEnd
        self.minuteEnd = minuteEnd
        self.message = message
    }
}

extension TimeMessage {
    var hourStart24: Int {
        switch ampm {
        case .am:
            return hourStart
        case .pm:
            return hourStart + 12
        }
    }

    var hourEnd24: Int {
        switch ampm {
        case .am:
            return hourEnd
        case .pm:
            return hourEnd + 12
        }
    }
}

extension TimeMessage {
    func matches(_ date: Date) -> Bool {
        let calendar = Calendar.current

        let hour = calendar.component(.hour, from: date)
        let minute = calendar.component(.minute, from: date)

        return (hourStart24, minuteStart) <= (hour, minute)
            && (hour, minute) <= (hourEnd24, minuteEnd)
    }
}
```

Using the above struct, you can declare your `messageArray` as:

```
let messageArray: [TimeMessage] = [
    TimeMessage(.am, 00, 00, 00, 01, "it's \nmidnight"),
    TimeMessage(.am, 00, 02, 02, 59, "it's very late (or early), \nto be up"),
    TimeMessage(.am, 03, 00, 03, 01, "are you ready \nfor the 03 am call?"),
    TimeMessage(.am, 03, 02, 03, 59, "go to sleep \ni'll let you know when it's \n4"),
    //...
]
```

And use it as:

```
let now = Date()
if let timeMessage = messageArray.first(where: {$0.matches(now)}) {
    print(timeMessage.message)
} else {
    print("No match")
}
```

Comment: The `am/pm`ness of the start and end time might be different. I would sugges making a time struct or tuple, like `(h: Int, m: Int, ampm: AmPm)`. That way you group together everything relevant to `start` and `end`, explicitly

Comment: @OOPer - this is a beautifuuly elegant answer. I accept this as the solution. Thank you sooooooo much!

Comment: just noticed @Alexander-ReinstateMonica's comment re. period spanning am/pm; thats a valid point. either i will have to force the periods not to do that or think about this a bit more. Thanks.

Comment: @Harvey, I believe you can modify my code fit for your actual purpose. But if you find some difficulty, you can start another thread or write a comment to this answer. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks @OOPer. I have modified your code, and used it. It works great! Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Use Dictionary of type [(Hour, Minute):String]

```
let hour = Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: Date())
let minute = Calendar.current.component(.minute, from: Date())

let messageArray: [(Int, Int):String] = [
 (0, 1): ["it's\nmidnight"],
 (2, 59): ["it's\very early"],
 (3, 01): ["that 3am call?"],
 (3, 59): ["come back at 4"]
]
```

Then you can use functional programming to check the order.

```
extension Dictionary where Key == (Int, Int) {
    func smallestValue<T: Value>(_ time: (Int, Int)) -> T? {
        let message: T? = nil
        for i in self {
            // Check for smallest case that is good
        }
        return message
    }
}

let message = messageArray.smallestValue((hour, minute)) ?? "Good job for being awake"
print(message)
```

Might need to make a struct in place for (Int, Int)

Comment: You're not really using the dictionary as a dictionary, you may as well use an array of tuples, or a `KeyValuePairs`

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica I see your point, I'm going to update my answer

Answer (score 1):

This is a little tricky, because `Date` models both a date and a time, and there's no counterpart that models just a time or just a date. I improvise by using a tuple of integers. It's probably not the best solution, but it's the best I could come up with (suggestions welcome!)

I would use a struct to model each message (with its `startTime`, `endTime`, and a computed property that lets you derive a `DateInterval` for it.

I would also make a `TimedMessageList`, which stores the look up table associating `DateInterval`s to `Message`s. Since look up involve checking intervals and not exact matches, a `Dictionary` won't really help us, so I just use an array of tuples, linear searching through them for every look up.

If the performance of that becomes a problem, you could explore tree-based data structures, like an [Interval Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree). Although that adds a lot of complexity, and would probably actually be slower than linear search until you start needing to look up thousands of entries or more.

A struct would be more appropriate here:

```
import Foundation

struct Message {
    let startTime: (h: Int, m: Int)
    let endTime: (h: Int, m: Int)
    let message: String

    var applicableTimeIntererval: DateInterval { 
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let now = Date()

        return DateInterval(
            start: calendar.date(bySettingHour: startTime.h, minute: startTime.m, second: 0, of: now)!, // TODO: are these safe to force unwrap?
            end:   calendar.date(bySettingHour:   endTime.h, minute:   endTime.m, second: 0, of: now)!  // TODO: are these safe to force unwrap?
        )
    }
}

struct TimedMessageList {
    let messagesByTimeInterval: [(dateInterval: DateInterval, message: Message)]

    init(_ messages: [Message]) {
        self.messagesByTimeInterval = messages.map { msg in (msg.applicableTimeIntererval, msg) }
    }

    func lookUpMessage(forTime timeTuple: (h: Int, m: Int)) -> Message? {
        let time = Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: timeTuple.h, minute: timeTuple.m, second: 0, of: Date())! // TODO: are these safe to force unwrap?
        return self.messagesByTimeInterval.first(where: { (timeInterval: DateInterval, msg: Message) -> Bool in
            timeInterval.contains(time)
        })?.message
    }
}

let messages = TimedMessageList([
    Message(startTime: (h: 00, m: 00), endTime: (h: 00, m: 01), message: """
    it's 
    midnight
    """),
    Message(startTime: (h: 00, m: 02), endTime: (h: 02, m: 59), message: """
    it's very late (or early), 
    to be up
    """),
    Message(startTime: (h: 03, m: 00), endTime: (h: 03, m: 01), message: """
    are you ready 
    for the 03 am call?
    """),
    Message(startTime: (h: 03, m: 02), endTime: (h: 03, m: 59), message: """
    go to sleep  
    i'll let you know when it's 
    4
    """),
])

let messageFor0305 = messages.lookUpMessage(forTime: (h: 03, m: 05))
if let messageFor0305 = messageFor0305 {
    print(messageFor0305.message)
} else {
    print("There is no message for 3:05")
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess in your method, I'd have to deconstruct time for every 'now' and check if message exists and return that to the label?

Comment: @Harvey I don't really understand your question, could you elaborate?

Comment: Thanks Alex - what I meant was, to use the messages.lookupMessage, I'd need to deconstruct every tick of time and pass it here to check. Im very new to this so I need to understand the lookup message function with time tuples better using playground.

Comment: @Harvey What precisely do you mean by "every tick of time"? If the API of that `lookUpMessage(forTime:)` doesn't suit the look ups you're trying to do, you can always change it

Comment: Thanks Alex, I understand.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a cool answer with ClosedRange. It allows you to create custom time ranges, and it can give you multiple messages depending on what time you've chosen.

```
struct Time { var hour: Int, min: Int }
extension Time: Comparable, Hashable {
    static func < (lhs: Time, rhs: Time) -> Bool {
        return lhs.hour < rhs.hour || (lhs.hour == rhs.hour && lhs.min < rhs.min)
    }
    init(_ h: Int,_ m: Int) { hour = h; min = m }
}

extension Dictionary where Key == ClosedRange<Time> {
    func has(_ time: Time) -> [Value] {
        var messages = [Value]()
        for i in self {
            time >= i.key.lowerBound && time <= i.key.upperBound ? { messages.append(i.value) }() : {}()
        }
        return messages
    }
}

let a = [
    Time(0, 0)...Time(0, 1): "it's midnight",
    Time(0, 2)...Time(2, 59): "it's very early",
    Time(3, 0)...Time(3, 1): "that 3am call?",
    Time(3, 2)...Time(3,59): "come back at 4",
    Time(3, 50)...Time(3, 59): "almost 4"
]

a.has(Time(3, 58))
// returns ["come back at 4", "almost 4"]
```

Comment: ooohhhh, I'm now spoilt for choice. This answer is both elegant and efficient. I like this!